# Using Pipeline to Avoid Data Leakage both for X and y

Tags: python, encoding, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, imputation

I followed the example at this link very closely: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html
but used a different dataset (found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult)

Unlike the example dataset, my dataset contains a couple of nulls in the y (aka 'target') column as well. I am wondering how I would build a pipeline similar to the one in the sklearn documentation that both transforms columns in X and y rather than just in X. This is what I have tried but of course it doesn't work because the 'target' feature has been dropped from X in order to allow for train_test_split:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

os.listdir()

df_train = pd.read_csv('data_train.txt', header=None)
df_test = pd.read_csv('data_test.txt', header=None)

names = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num', 'marital-status', 
        'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital-sign', 'capital-loss', 
        'hours-per-week', 'native-country', 'target']

df = pd.concat([df_train, df_test], axis=0)

df.head()

df.columns = names

Data Leakage Example - Preprocessing is done on the entire dataset

df_leakage = df.copy()

#Exploring nulls: 
df_leakage[df_leakage.isnull().any(axis=1)]

There are only two nulls so it would be safe to discard them but for the purposes of this demo we will impute values 

from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#Defining numeric features and the transformations we will apply to them
numeric_features = ['capital-sign', 'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week', 'education-num']
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

#Defining categorical features and the transformations we will apply to them
categorical_features = ['marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'native-country']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

#Defining categorical ordinal features and the transformations we will apply to them
#Note: we already have a education-continuous feature available but we will demo how to apply an ordinal transformation:
ordinal_features = ['education']
ordinal_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder())])

#Defining categorical ordinal features and the transformations we will apply to them
#Note: we already have a education-continuous feature available but we will demo how to apply an ordinal transformation:
ordinal_features = ['education']
label_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('label', LabelEncoder())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
        ('ord', ordinal_transformer, ordinal_features),
        ('lab', label_transformer, label_features),
    ])

# Append classifier to preprocessing pipeline.
# Now we have a full prediction pipeline.
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                      ('classifier', LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs'))])

X = df_leakage.drop('target', axis=1)
y = df_leakage['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("model score: %.3f" % clf.score(X_test, y_test))

Error log (partial):
    658             columns = list(key)
    659 
--> 660         return [all_columns.index(col) for col in columns]
    661 
    662     elif hasattr(key, 'dtype') and np.issubdtype(key.dtype, np.bool_):

ValueError: 'y' is not in list
```

Obviously, I could easily apply the transformation to y separately, before any of these other transformations take place. I think it would be fine to handle character strings errors e.g. ".<=50K" vs "<=50K". But if I want to impute the value of y with its mean, the value imputed would depend on the specific choice of y_train -- thus causing some data leakage.

How would I be able to use the pipeline library to do this effectively?

Comment: My 2 cents on this is that if you have y values you need to impute, then you should rather discard them from your training set and that's it. What's the point of training a model against imputed values? Most likely, this will only harm your model in the end.

Comment: That is a very good point! I only have two rows with null target var so I will definitely do that. Just out of curiosity, what if I had many more nulls in y? Like 50% of the dataset. What would you do in that situation?

Comment: I would still discard the missing data. If you really have very little data that is labeled, then you could start thinking about semi-supervised learning, but this is a totally different way of proceeding.

Comment: Glad it helped! :)